# Django UNIQUE constraint failed: Site_coach.user_id

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, unique-constraint

I'am developing a website in Python Django. I have a template Register.html with a function "Register" I would like that my users put their additional informations on this page after they registered on an another page.
My problem is when my users put their additional informations for the first time in my form it work but then if my users want to update their informations from the same form on the same page, they receive an error "UNIQUE constraint failed: Site_coach.user_id" 
I'am a beginner. Can you help me to fix this error ?

My view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import RegisterForm

def Register(request):

    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.user = request.user
        form.save()
    return render(request, 'Register.html', {'form': form})
```

My Site/models.py

```
class coach(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Telephone = models.IntegerField()
    TestResult = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    Level = models.TextField()
```

My users/models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, UserManager
from django.db import models

class CustomUserManager(UserManager):
    pass
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    objects = CustomUserManager()
```

My forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import coach
class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = coach
        exclude = ('user','TestResult')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the instance of the object being modified, otherwise a new one will be created and the save will fail because it's a `OneToOne`:

```
def Register(request):
    try:
        coach_instance = coach.objects.get(user=request.user)
    except coach.DoesNotExist:
        coach_instance = coach(user=request.user)
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES, instance=coach_instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.user = request.user
        form.save()
    return render(request, 'Register.html', {'form': form})
```

I'm assuming `RegisterForm` is a `ModelForm` with model `coach`, you can adjust accordingly.

Comment: Thank you ! but I don't understand what I need to adjust in my form ?

Comment: You're welcome. You may not need to adjust anything. If `RegisterForm` is indeed a `ModelForm` with model `coach`, this code should just work. If it's not, you need to get the right object to pass as the instance to the form.

Comment: I adjust my code. now I have  "form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES, instance=coach_instance)"  but I have now directly an error on this page "full_clean() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"

Comment: Can't imagine where that's coming from. Can you add the full error trace to the question?

Comment: Yes sure ! So I try to open Register.html and i get the error.  This is the full trace http://dpaste.com/29NKN68

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure it out from this. You do have an unusual structure for the view. It may be worth trying to make the view similar to [a more common approach](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#the-view), although I don't know if it will help.

Comment: I figured out why I had "full_clean()" error.... It was just distraction error :/  But now I have another error when I want to submit my form "DoesNotExist
Exception Value:coach matching query does not exist." I changed my view in order to have a more common structure and I continue to have this error

Comment: Ok, that one I understand. I edited the answer with a possible solution. You `try` to get the coach object and create a new one if it doesn't exist. There may be more elegant ways to lay out the code, but that's the general idea.

Comment: Thank you for your answers ! it helped me a lot !  Now everything is working correctly !